# Batch script to find a hidden folder on a remote computer, list the last date modifed, and output to log

Tags: batch-file, hidden, exists, last-modified, not-exists

I am looking for a Windows batch script that I can run from my admin workstation that will find a specific hidden folder on the C: drive of remote machines, tell me if it exists or not, give me the last date modified, and output the results to a log file. The folder path is something like, "C:/ProgramData/Folder1/Folder2". The "ProgramData" folder is hidden and "Folder2" is the folder that I want all the details from (if it exists, last date modified). I would like to incorporate this with the use of PSEXEC if possible.

I have looked all around for something that will work and found some scripts that tell me if the folder exists or not; but I cannot seem to find my exact scenario. I am familiar with scripts but am no expert by any stretch of the imagination. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

**EDIT:**

Okay here is what I have so far. I was able to use a command prompt to list the subdirectory that I was looking for on a specific computer by using the `DIR` command. It was something like this:

```
dir C:\ParentFolder\ChildFolder /ad /o-d /b
```

This shows a list of directories within the "ChildFolder" directory. The output would be something like:

```
dir C:\ParentFolder\ChildFolder /ad /o-d /b
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
```

So what I need now is to incorporate a way to just show the folder in this group that had the most recent modification. For example if "folder2" was the most recently modified folder in the group, I would like my command line to just display "folder2 04/08/14 04:13 PM

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `dir /?` then specifically `/T`. Also `if /?`, You need `if exist`, to check if a file or directory exists. The following will grab the date and time of a folder's last write, if it exists.

```
@echo off
set folder=C:\ProgramData\Folder1\Folder2
if exist %folder% (
    for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2" %%a in ('dir %folder%') do set writetime=%%a %%b & goto :break
) else echo %folder% Does Not Exist & goto :EOF
:break
echo %folder%   %writetime%
```

To write the output to a file you can use the `>` (write) or `>>` (append) operators. `echo Mate >> logfile.txt`.

Comment: Okay, I tried to use this script as a .bat; I saved it to my Desktop as "If Folder Exists.bat"; I created a directory on my Desktop called "Test_Directory". I added this last line to the very end of your script: echo >> Test_Directory/if-it-exists.log 2>&1. I am not getting any result in the "Test_Directory" folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply to this sooner, I was away for a while. Try turning echo on, and seeing what the command prompt says. Is the script even getting to your echo to the log file?

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply; I just used PowerShell to get what I needed. Thanks for all the help